# Regex - Remove all but 2 digits

Tags: regex, bash, sed

If you have the following strings, how would you reduce them to just the first 2 digits?

```
FOO='1.2.3'
BAR='4.5.6.7x'
```

Desired outputs

```
FOO='1.2'
BAR='4.5'
```

This sed expression does the exact opposite of what I want.

```
echo $FOO | sed 's/^[0-9]\+.[0-9]//g'
.3
```

How could I invert this sed expression?

Answer (score 3):

```
$  echo $BAR | sed -r 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/'
4.5

$ echo $FOO | sed -r 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/'
1.2
```

- `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)` matches the first two parts, say `1.2`. Saved in capture group 1, `\1`
- `.*` matches the rest

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without `regex` if you like to try some other than `sed`

```
echo $BAR | awk -F. '{print $1 FS $2}'
4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash builtin commands:

```
BAR='4.5.6.7x'
IFS="." set -- $BAR
echo $1.$2
```

Output:

```
4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by creating a function like this, using [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):

```
f() {
    numbers=( ${1//./ } )
    echo ${numbers[0]}.${numbers[1]}
}
```

Or without arrays:

```
f() {
    TMP=${1#*.}
    echo ${1%%.*}.${TMP%%.*}
}
```

#### Example

```
$ FOO='1.2.3'
$ BAR='4.5.6.7x'
$ f $FOO
1.2
$ f $BAR
4.5
```